# KVM QEMU looses USB devices

Tags: windows-vista, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have a KVM Qemu setup. I'm mapping a USB device to a VM running windows vista. I get the device mapped, and all is well for some time. Suddenly the device disappears in Vista. If I do "lsusb" in linux it shows up, and if I run "info usbhost" in qm it shows the device is being mapped.

Any ideas? There isn't much point in using

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the same behavior in linux guests? Might be a driver issue, or anywhere in the stack really

Comment: Well the device is a Sentinal UltraPro USB dongle. What baffles me is that it doesn't even show up under Device Manager after it disappears. It's as if QEMU says "it exists" and Vista says "what are you talking about?"